# Weird shading in my faces

Tags: shaders

I have used blender for some time and have never seen something like this, I tried: Changing normals; Flat/smooth shading; deleting the faces; making the faces planar, and I can't find the solution.

It also appears in the render.[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file?

Comment: is this imported from a different 3D app? or modeled in blender directly?

Comment: It does look like non planar faces. But without looking at the file is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing double vertices and recalculating the normals.

Comment: Please consider adding *how* to remove doubles and *how* to recalculate normals.

Answer (score 1):

Without viewing a file it's hard to say with certainty, but it appears that the 3 edges in question are slightly raised. If you have already checked normals, double vertices etc. then a possible fix for this would be as follows (using a circle):

If you do not have the *Mesh: loop tools* add-on enabled, then enable it in *user preferences>add-on tab* under the community add-ons.

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)

[image]

Select all (in *edit mode*)  and press <kbd>W</kbd> then choose *loop tools>flatten*

[image]